# Object file .git/objects/ is empty from git pull or status?

Tags: java, android, git, github

git pull origin develop

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-H81M-S:~/Desktop/petsearch$ git pull origin develop
Password : 
error: object file .git/objects/fa/8f28c29e3537602215a2f11d73efedad3dbb75 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/fa/8f28c29e3537602215a2f11d73efedad3dbb75 is empty
fatal: loose object fa8f28c29e3537602215a2f11d73efedad3dbb75 (stored in .git/objects/fa/8f28c29e3537602215a2f11d73efedad3dbb75) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: try to instead write git pull origin master

Comment: You have a corrupted (damaged) repository. This is not due to running `git pull`; it's usually due to a computer crash, unexpected reboot, removal of USB drive without proper shutdown first, or attempting to use something like Dropbox to hold a repository. Search for "git corrupt repository" (on stackoverflow or using Google).